# Lucene/Solr Instant Development using jQuery/PHP/AJAX/JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to UI technologies like JQuery, AJAX, PHP etc.

I am building a Google Instant like feature. My search engine infrastructure at backend is pretty fast and returns results even for Tera Bytes of data in super quick time.

I have a PHP function in a class that returns me an array:

```
solrsearch.php

    class SolrSearch{
        ...
        ...
        public function find( $q ){
           ...
           ...
           return $found;
        }
    }

$found is a key value pair something like documentID=>Data
```

When I dry run it i.e. on a console (not on a browser) with a test string and not using $q input variable everything seems to be fine and I print $found and it prints the values.

Now my html file with embedded javascript looks like this, so basically here I am capturing each key press on the textbox and doing a get request

```
testjson.html

    <html>
    ...
    <body>

    <div align="center"><p><font size = 7 face="Verdana"> Search: <input type="text" id="term" size = 60 style="font-size:22pt"/>
    <table id="results">
    </table>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#term').keyup( function() {
      $.get('search_json.php?q='+escape($('#term').val()), function(data) {
        html = '<table id="results">';
        $.each( data, function( index, val ) {
            html += '<tr><td class="document"><b>'+index.key+'</b>&nbsp;';
            html += 'Dated '+val.value+'</td></tr>';
        } );
        html += '</html>';
        $('#results').replaceWith( html );
      } );
    } );
    } );
    </script>
    ...
    ...
    </html>
```

And then finally here is my

```
search_json.php

$s = new SolrSearch();
print json_encode( $s->find( $_REQUEST['q'] ) );
```

Even the json encoded string is working perfectly fine and prints the json though on a console (not on browser)

Here is the problem I am facing: On the browser when I run testjson.html which just has a textBox and I input some strings so I dont get any results displayed back on the browser. When I debug it using Fiddler (HTTP Debugging Proxy) I can see AJAX get requests in that.

Any help would be appreciated. If there is anything else I can add to the question which is required I will be more than happy to do that.

**EDIT:**

I further debugged and printed $q in the find function in solrsearch.php and it did not print the value that means the value is not getting passed from search_json.php however I can see the GET requests on Fiddler.

Comment: Have you try using $.getJSON instead of $.get as it is more appropriate if you are expecting JSON data and will guaranteed that, if the JSON is correct, you get a object as data. Does the callback function actually execute? Have you try console.log the data see if it is correct?

Comment: @gillesc: Thanks for your help. Actually the query is not being passed to find function of solrsearch.php from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this line:

- `html += '</html>';`

should be

- `html += '</table>';`

By the way, instead of using `$('#results').replaceWith( html );` try with `$('#results').html( html );`

Edited:
Instead of $.get(), try with $.ajax():

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'search_json.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { q: escape($('#term').val() },
}).done(function(resp) {
   //Your html code with response options
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited the body section in the html in my question. I tried these stuff but did not work.

Comment: I have Edited my question with some more relevant debugging information.

Comment: Try with removing these two lines from your javascript code `html = '<table id="results">';` and `html += '</table>';`

Answer (score 0):

If your front end uses HTML you definitely have to take a look on AJAX-SOLR

AJAX Solr is a JavaScript library for creating user interfaces to Apache Solr

- Play with the [demo site](http://evolvingweb.github.com/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.html)
- Follow the [tutorial](http://wiki.github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/reuters-tutorial)
- Browse the [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr)
- Read the [documentation](http://evolvingweb.github.com/ajax-solr/docs/index.html)
- Explore the [code](http://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr)